# Adding a character in the middle of a string

Tags: php, string, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

There's probably a simple solution to this that will cause a facepalm. I have time stored as a 4 character long string ie 1300.

I'm trying to display that string as 13:00. I feel like there has to be a solution to this that is more elegant than what I'm doing at the moment.

I currently have:

```
$startTime = get_field($dayStart, $post->ID);
$endTime = get_field($dayEnd, $post->ID);

        for ($x=0; $x = 4; $x++){

            if(x == 2){
                $ST .= ':';
                $ET .= ':';
            } else {
                $ST .= $startTime[x];
                $ET .= $endTime[x];
            }

        }

$startTime = $ST;
$endTime = $ET;
```

The string will always be 4 characters long.

Comment: A remark about the answer chosen: apparently at the time of the question no one was shrewd enough to find the unique function that does what is asked. The answer chosen works, but Frankey's answer is the correct answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$time = "1300";    
$time = substr($time,0,2).':'.substr($time,2,2);
```

***Edit:***

Here is a general solution to this problem:

```
function insertAtPosition($string, $insert, $position) {
    return implode($insert, str_split($string, $position));
}
```

Comment: And second returns "50:0" if $time = "500";

Comment: must be considered from the end of

Comment: @Ethan Good tone is a universal solution. but you coped with task :)

Comment: there is a native php function for the custom function one you wrote in your edit, see my answer below.

Comment: What happens to your general solution when position is zero? Or when the length of string is multiple times larger than position? ... :)

Comment: => "1111111111111"
>>> $time = substr($time,0,5).'-'.substr($time,5,7).'-'.substr($time,7,1);
=> "11111-1111111-1"

Answer (score 22):

I favor this solution as it is just one function

```
substr_replace('1300', ':', 2, 0);
```

http://php.net/substr_replace

Comment: I'm here wondering why this answer wasn't the accepted answer, if it's the most correct. I, being the author, would come back and select the correct answer to this one here

Answer (score 6):

```
implode(":",str_split($time,2));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
substr_replace( $yourVar, ':', -2, 0 );
```

Will make 945 result in 9:45 and 1245 in 12:45.